# Get CSS from webpage and load it in android webview

Tags: android, css, webview

I have to create a dialog which contains the response from a server. The problem is that in the webpage, the response is formatted nicely in CSS (I copied this from inspect element within browser)

```
box-sizing:border-box;
color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
display:block;
font-family:"PT Sans Narrow";
font-size:14.992px;
font-weight:400;
height:132px;
line-height:29.984px;
text-align:center;
text-size-adjust:100%;
width:437px;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba
```

But the response received in the android app is just basic html code with some divs:

```
<div id="bp-kunde">
        <h2 id="bp-kundenname">Kartennummer wurde nicht gefunden.</h2>
          <span id="bp-kundennr" class="card-number">&nbsp;<br/></span>
    </div>
<div  id="bp-punkte" class="price">
                        &nbsp;
        <span>&nbsp;<br/></span>
</div>
```

How can I get the CSS from the website and load it into my Android WebView?